# Twitter4j error on processing

Tags: twitter, processing, twitter4j

Im trying to follow [this](http://blog.blprnt.com/blog/blprnt/updated-quick-tutorial-processing-twitter) tutorial:

```
//Build an ArrayList to hold all of the words that we get from the
 imported tweets 
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();  
 void setup() {   //Set the size of the stage, and the background to black. 
 size(550,550);  
 background(0); 
 smooth();
      //Credentials   ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();  
 cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("lPFSpjBppo5u4KI5xEXaQ");  
 cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("SYt3e4xxSHUL1gPfM9bxQIq6Jf34Hln9T1q9KGCPs");
 cb.setOAuthAccessToken("17049577-Yyo3AEVsqZZopPTr055TFdySop228pKKAZGbJDtnV");
 cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("6ZjJBebElMBiOOeyVeh8GFLsROtXXtKktXALxAT0I");
     //Make the twitter object and prepare the query  
 Twitter twitter = new  
 TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();   
 Query query = new Query("#OWS");  
  query.setRpp(100);
     //Try making the query request.   try {
     QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
     ArrayList tweets = (ArrayList) result.getTweets();

     for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size(); i++) {
       Tweet t = (Tweet) tweets.get(i);
       String user = t.getFromUser();
       String msg = t.getText();
       Date d = t.getCreatedAt();
       println("Tweet by " + user + " at " + d + ": " + msg);

       //Break the tweet into words
       String[] input = msg.split(" ");
       for (int j = 0;  j < input.length; j++) {
        //Put each word into the words ArrayList
        words.add(input[j]);
       }
     };   }   catch (TwitterException te) {
     println("Couldn't connect: " + te);   }; }   void draw() {   //Draw a faint black rectangle over what is currently on the stage so
 it fades over time.   fill(0,1);   rect(0,0,width,height);
       //Draw a word from the list of words that we've built   int i = (frameCount % words.size());   String word = words.get(i);
       //Put it somewhere random on the stage, with a random size and colour   fill(255,random(50,150));   textSize(random(10,30));  
 text(word, random(width), random(height)); }
```

But i get the following error when i run the code in processing. `cannot find class or type named tweet`

Ive added the twitter4j libraries by dragging and dropping to the processing IDE.

Im using processing 2.1 and twitter4j3.05

Any suggestions?

Comment: This has big formatting issues.  I just rejected a change-attempt that made the formatting worse.  Hope someone else can improve it

Comment: I added link where full code can be found if that helps, see this line 1

Comment: Content on this site is favored over external sources, since they can change or go away.  Generally, if you can't ask the question without pasting huge code, you may well have a 'basic research' problem that can be solved by better searching of this site or google / docs.

Comment: I think this code uses a different version of twitter4j. Tweet (with a capital T) has been removed since vrs 3.0. They kind of have being replaced by Status. Check the [documentation](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic example using twitter4j 3.0.5.

```
import java.util.*;

List<Status>statuses = null;

TwitterFactory twitterFactory;
Twitter twitter;

void setup() {     
  size(100, 100);    
  background(0); 

  connectTwitter();    
  getTimeline();  
  getSearchTweets();
}  

void draw() {     
  background(0);
}  




// Initial connection
void connectTwitter() {  
  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();  
  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("xxx");
  cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxx");
  cb.setOAuthAccessToken("xxx");
  cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxx"); 

  twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());    
  twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();  

  println("connected");
} 

// Get your tweets
void getTimeline() {     
  try {        
    statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
  }   
  catch(TwitterException e) {         
    println("Get timeline: " + e + " Status code: " + e.getStatusCode());
  }     
  for (Status status:statuses) {               
    println(status.getUser().getName() + ": " + status.getText());
  }
}  
// Search for tweets

void getSearchTweets() {           
  try {        
    Query query = new Query("love");            
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);              
    for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {              
      println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());
    }
  }   
  catch (TwitterException e) {            
    println("Search tweets: " + e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know where i can get tutorials for twitter4j 3.x

Comment: i get an error for this line: List<Status>statuses = null; it says list is amiguious

Comment: It works here, twitter4j 3.0.5 and processing 2.1. I didn't get any error... Ambiguous means that two different classes uses same name, but it's weird for a java core class as List... Did you import java.util.* ? About tutorials, there are a lot of [code examples](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) at their site.